# In Office 365 Not able to Fetch Column Name "Folder" from Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-list

In **Office 365** I have created one ***custom list*** and in that created one Column as **"Folder"**. When I have tried to access this field using RestAPI or CSOM or using U2U Caml query I am not able to get this fields information.

May be reserved name or reserved keyword
I have also seen an internal name of this column is  **"Folder"**.

Not sure what is an issue with this column apart from other columns I am able to fetch information.

Also asked a question in SharePoint community as well. [Reference link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-365/Not-able-to-Fetch-Column-Name-quot-Folder-quot-from-Custom-List/m-p/235739#M15440)

Comment: strange, even i tested. every field value is coming except Folder column.

Comment: Yes very strange, If this column name not supported then It should restrict while creating this Column. So User we aware of this feature or issue in prior.

Comment: have you tried create column name folder (all small caps)? I am able to do CAML for folder instead Folder.

Answer (score 0):

"Folder" is a special name in SharePoint and it will have conflict in the list. Try to create the column with another name for example FolderForTest and then test if it works.